# PDFlib breaking tables and adding dynamic text to the page

Tags: pdflib

I'm using PDFlib to generate tables. I break these tables based on sort column in the database. I want to add a heading to each page with the ever changing value of the sort column. How can I identify the sort column from the table as the tables are added to the pages ?

Answer (score 0):

I worked out a solution that might be helpful to others. Instead of creating all the tables in one fell swoop I broke them into a separate array based on the sorting of the data then processed each table section independently one at a time.

Added table cells / rows to an array like so...

$tableArray[$sortA] = PDF_add_table_cell($p, $tableArray[$sortA], 1, $rowNum++, $sortB,$sortB_opts);

Then after all tables were built fit them to the pages like so

foreach($tableArray as $tbl){

$tabresult = PDF_fit_table($p, $tbl, $newllx, $lly, $newurx, $ury, $fit_opts);

}